# How can I use pytesseract to read numbers that have a white text colour?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I am trying to use `pytesseract` to read a number in an image; the image consist just of that number, and the number is quite clear on the image, but the text is in white colour.

Here is the image:
[image_of_number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dTAX.png)

I tried the following code:

```
def action_behind_me(): 

    stack2 = pyautogui.screenshot(f"{sys.path[0]}/stack2.png", region=(590,1173, 65, 37))
stack2.show()

    new_im = stack2.resize((170, 100))
new_im.show()
    pot_size = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_im, config="--psm 6")


print(action_behind_me())`
```

But the output is `None`. I have tried the above code with other images, where the colour of the number is not white and it works perfectly fine.

I'm not sure if it is the white number that makes it hard for it to be read.